# Regular expression doesn't match if text contains certain characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a string containing certain characters, but not containing others. The problem is that if the string contains an allowed character, the expression finds a match, even though it contains invalid ones (nothing unusual, but not what I want).
The expression I'm using looks like this `([^abc][def])+`.
So the question is: Can I define a group of characters, that if contained within the string, will stop the expression from matching the string?

Comment: Which flavour of regex are you using?

Comment: What is the string made of? Letters only? Any characters?

Comment: Word characters, except some letters.

Comment: show some inputs and whether they should match or not.

Comment: The tricky part is that I want to match all that `\w` contains, except some chars. Is that even possible?

Comment: @xyu, sure. Eg: `[^\Wabc]` will match everything in `\w` except `abc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to anchor your expression, to make sure no other characters are in the string. For example:

```
^[chars]+\z
```

Or you can simply invert the character class and you will get a match if an invalid character is present:

```
[^chars]
```

If you want to combine such checks with other expressions in the same regex you could use a lookahead:

```
^(?=[chars]+\z)expression
```